# Evolution doesn't work with university wireless network

Tags: wireless, evolution, connection, mail, client

I'm fairly new to the Linux world, specifically to Ubuntu 11.10. I started using Evolution mail to put all my email accounts, calendars and life in order, but for some reason it CANNOT update anything when I'm using my university's wireless connection. The same happened when I used Outlook (back when I used Windows). I cannot figure out what the problem is. I even disable the IP blocklist I put Transmission BitTorrent and nothing. What can I do? I really need Evolution to update constantly or else I'm screwed here.

I'd really appreciate anyone's help.
Ikki F.

Comment: If you had problem with outlook as well and if you can use any evolution on other networks than school network then I suppose you should check with your school IT department. Sidenote: try thunderbird just to make sure its school network that needs fixing :)

Comment: Can you verify that using the browser does work? IE: your wireless setup is working and no special authentication mechanisms or proxy problems are happening for normal browsing.

Answer (score 3):

I assume all other networking stuff works. My best guess is that your university blocks certain ports or protocols. I don't really see a reason as to why email should be blocked, but I may as an administrator do this to prevent users from using insecure (unencripted) connections to read their mail. Try using a different port. Often mail providers have an encrypted port, and an unencrypted one.

Greetings, Niklas

Comment: To wisemonkey:
I'll check with the IT deapartment as you suggest. This is annoying.

To Beanow: Yes, the browers works, but sometimes I get desconnected and the internet runs very slow. 

To niklasfi:
Your suggestion sounds helpful. How can I do that?